# MySQL top X results within each group

Tags: mysql, optimization

Is there a more efficient way to grab the top X results from each group?

You can ignore any field in the sqlfiddle that is not used in the query.

The query:

```
SET @num := 0, @item_id := '';
SELECT `item_id`, `user_id`, total_hoarded FROM (
        SELECT `item_id`, `user_id`, total_hoarded,
                @num := IF(@item_id = x.`item_id`, @num + 1, 1) AS ROW_NUMBER,
                @item_id := x.`item_id` AS dummy
        FROM (
                SELECT `item_id`, `user_id`, COUNT(*) AS total_hoarded
                FROM `player_items`
                GROUP BY `item_id`, `user_id`
                ORDER BY `item_id`, total_hoarded DESC
        ) AS x
) AS y WHERE y.ROW_NUMBER <= 10;");
```

The demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75bc7/1

**Description of query**:

(Starting from the most nested query) It grabs and groups all of the rows by item_id and and user_id so that we can do some aggregate functions to figure out how many items each user has.

The next level up then attaches a row_number to each row, so that the final query can simply grab all rows less than X (in this case the top 10 users for each grouping).

SQLFiddle is limited in terms of how big the sample can be, so it only shows data for two items, and a handful of users. Not enough to fully populate the top 10, but enough to show what I am doing.

**The options (I am considering)**:

- Leave query as is.
- Do a standard query grouping and loop it through PHP to grab the top 10
- Other? (Haven't thought of any others)

**Notes**:

I realise that I might not have given enough detail, so let me know what you need. I am only looking at a general way to approach this. The query above takes about 5mins to run on a table with 30mill rows. This is not a big deal though, as the query is only run once every hour.

Breaking the query into smaller parts might run faster, but the table gets written to a lot, so queries tend to get locked out.

Comment: Thanks mirk. Was having trouble formatting the query properly... and took the lazy way out by dropping in pastebin.